# CountDownTimer trivia game score - Android (java)

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a trivia game that displays 10 questions and they each have a 10 second timer.  I have 2 problems that do not function correctly.

Firstly, If the timer runs out on a question, it displays the next question but the timer does not reset.  The textviews stay at "Time's up!" and "Time Elapsed: 10000" instead of restarting the timer on the new question that is displayed.

Lastly, on the Results page the correct score is not displayed in the textview.  The percentage textview displays correctly but the score textview displays "android.widget.TextView@416473c" or some other random memory location.

The program never crashes just functions incorrectly.  Any code structure or other suggestions is much appreciated!  This is my first android mobile app attempt and I am slowly and strugglingly through it.  Yet enjoying it!  :)

QuesteionView.java

```
public class QuestionView extends Activity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questionviewmain);

        answer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        answer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        answer3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        answer4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
        queries = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");
        timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
        timeElapsedView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeElapsedView);
        cdTimer = new Timer(startTime, interval);
        loadQuestion();
    }

    public void loadQuestion() {

        if(i == 9) {    
            endQuiz();  
        } else {    
            if(!timerHasStarted) {
                cdTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = true;
            } else {
                cdTimer.cancel();
                timerHasStarted = false;
            }
            answer = queries.get(i).getCorrectAnswer();
            question.setText(queries.get(i).getQuery());

            answer1.setText(queries.get(i).getA1());
            answer2.setText(queries.get(i).getA2());
            answer3.setText(queries.get(i).getA3());
            answer4.setText(queries.get(i).getA4());

            answer1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    queries.get(i).setSelectedAnswer(0);
                    if(answer == 0) {
                        correctAnswers++;
                        nextQuestion();
                    } else {
                        wrongAnswers++;
                        nextQuestion();
                    }
                }
            });

           //same type of code for buttons for answers 2 through 4.
                } 
    }

    public void nextQuestion() {
        score = score + timeElapsed;
        i++;
        loadQuestion();
    }

    public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {     
        public Timer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            if(i == 9) {
                cdTimer.cancel();
            } else {
                timer.setText("Time's up!");
                timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(startTime));
                wrongAnswers++;
                nextQuestion();
            }
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("Time remain: " + Long.toString(millisUntilFinished));
            timeElapsed = startTime - millisUntilFinished;
            timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + Long.toString(timeElapsed));
        }
    }

    public void endQuiz() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionView.this, Results.class);
        intent.putExtra("correctAnswers", correctAnswers);
        intent.putExtra("wrongAnswers", wrongAnswers);
        intent.putExtra("score", score);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("queries", queries);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Results.java

```
    public class Results extends Activity {

    QuestionView qv = new QuestionView();
    ArrayList<Question> queryList = qv.getQueries();

    int cAnswers;
    int wAnswers;

    long score;

    ArrayList<Question> qs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resultsmain);

        cAnswers = getIntent().getIntExtra("correctAnswers", -1);
        wAnswers = getIntent().getIntExtra("wrongAnswers", -1);
        score = getIntent().getLongExtra("score", -1);

        qs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");

        Button mainmenuBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainmenuBtn);
        mainmenuBtn.setText("Main Menu");

        mainmenuBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                restart();
            }
        });

        showResults();
    }

    public void showResults() {

        ArrayList<TextView> tList = new ArrayList<TextView>(9);

        TextView header = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header);
        header.setText("SUMMARY");

        TextView percentage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        percentage.setText(Integer.toString(10 * cAnswers) + "%");

        TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        String s = "" + score;
        score.setText(s);

        TextView q1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q1);
        TextView q2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q2);
        TextView q3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q3);
        TextView q4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q4);
        TextView q5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q5);
        TextView q6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q6);
        TextView q7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q7);
        TextView q8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q8);
        TextView q9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q9);
        TextView q10 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q10);

        tList.add(q1);
        tList.add(q2);
        tList.add(q3);
        tList.add(q4);
        tList.add(q5);
        tList.add(q6);
        tList.add(q7);
        tList.add(q8);
        tList.add(q9);
        tList.add(q10);

        for(int i = 0; i < tList.size(); i++) {
            tList.get(i).setText(qs.get(i).getQuery());
            if(qs.get(i).getSelectedAnswer() == qs.get(i).getCorrectAnswer()) {
                tList.get(i).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                tList.get(i).setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }

    public void restart() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Results.this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted huge amounts of code, but you've given no indication of what you've tried to fix the problem. Additionally, your title refers to an exception - but there's no mention of it in your question body.

Comment: use `ArrayList<TextView> tList = new ArrayList<TextView>(9);` instead of `ArrayList<TextView> tList = new ArrayList<TextView>(10);`

Comment: please cut out the code you know that it is working.

Comment: I apologize for the title, I fixed it.  I was doing too many things at once and put the incorrect title on it.  I will edit my code with where I think the problem is.

Comment: @user1866707 : and also change  `for(int i = 0; i < 1tList.size(); i++)`

Comment: I have edited my code and taken out all the code that yall did not really need to see.

Comment: Thank you prosper K.  I correct both places to make my code my elegant! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From all of that code, this is what I think is happening

> Firstly, If the timer runs out on a question, it displays the next question but the timer does not reset. The textviews stay at "Time's up!" and "Time Elapsed: 10000" instead of restarting the timer on the new question that is displayed.

This appears to be due to you not setting your `timerHasStarted` variable to false after the time runs out so I would set that to false probably when you load your next question or after you show the results.

> Lastly, on the Results page the correct score is not displayed in the textview. The percentage textview displays correctly but the score textview displays "android.widget.TextView@416473c" or some other random memory location.

This is because you are setting your q variables to the textview and getting the id. You need something like `q1.getText().toString()`

You have multiple variables with the same name score. So change it to

```
  TextView score2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
  String s = "" + score;
  score2.setText(s);
```

Comment: All of the q variables (q1 through q10) display the correct output.  The only TextView that is not working is the "score" textview.  I have edited my opening post to include the whole Results class.

Comment: Also, fixing the timerHasStarted variable fixed the other problem.  Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you got it figured out. Sorry, I just got a chance to check this and sorry about the confusion with the q variables.

Answer (score 0):

the score displays not what you expected because you assigned the `String s = "" + score` where `score` is what you named for the `Textview` which obviously not an integer and not equivalent to the score that the user has. :)