# How to make a timer on my Android quiz application?

Tags: android

I am making an Android quiz application and I would like for it to have a timer.. 15 seconds. When the timer finishes it moves to a new question. I really did not tried anything because I really don't have a clue, except a choronometer but it seems like a bad solution... the code:

I have added this code for a countdown... and you see when it finishes it goes to a method generateQuestion().. now it generates a new question but the answers are mixed up.. it shows answer from some other questions.. How do I solve this?

```
package com.matej.hajdukkviz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Glavno extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

int score  = 0;
int counter = 0;
boolean ajme = true;

TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, countdown;
Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;

ArrayList<Question> qsts = new ArrayList<Question>();
List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<String> allAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();

Random rng = new Random();
Question nextQuestion;

Question qjedan = new Question(
        "Q1",

        "Correct answer - q1",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q1",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q1",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q1"
        );
Question q2 = new Question(
        "Q2",

        "Correct answer - q2",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q2",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q2",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q2"
        );
Question q3 = new Question(
        "Q3",

        "Correct answer - q3",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q3",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q3",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q3"
        );


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.pitanja);

// ADD THE QUESTIONS IN THE ArrayList qsts

 new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             textView4.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             generateQuestion();
             textView2.setText("VRIJEME!");
             textView2.setTextColor(Color.RED);

         }
          }.start();

    qsts.add(qjedan);           
    qsts.add(q2);
    qsts.add(q3);

    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    textView3.setText("Rezultat: " + score);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);

    generateQuestion();

}

    public void generateQuestion(){

        while(ajme = true){

            int nxt = rng.nextInt(3);

            if (!generated.contains(nxt)){

                generated.add(nxt);

                nextQuestion = qsts.get(nxt);

                textView1.setText(nextQuestion.questionText);

                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.correctAnswerText);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer1);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer2);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer3);

                Collections.shuffle(allAnswers);

                btn1.setText(allAnswers.get(0));
                btn2.setText(allAnswers.get(1));
                btn3.setText(allAnswers.get(2));
                btn4.setText(allAnswers.get(3));

                break;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button b = (Button)v;
        String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

        if (counter == 3) {

            Intent theIntent = new Intent(this, Score.class);
            theIntent.putExtra("somename", score);  
            startActivity(theIntent);

            finish();   // Added this method call
        }

        else if(buttonText.equals(nextQuestion.correctAnswerText)) { 

            counter++;

            AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ads);
            ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

            textView2.setText("TOČNO!");
            textView2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            textView3.setText("Rezultat: " + (score += 10));

            allAnswers.clear();
            generateQuestion();

            return;
        } 

        else{

            counter++;

            AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ads);
            ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

            textView2.setText("NETOČNO!");
            textView2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            textView3.setText("Rezultat: " + (score -= 5));

            allAnswers.clear();
            generateQuestion();

            return; 
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: This shouldn't be your go-to place for things like these. First, do your research.

Comment: did you try SystemClock.sleep(2000); between each view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to write the code for you, however, in this situation I think you want a [CountdownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). It is very easy to use. Here is the example from the docs.

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
  }.start();
```

Basically, the `onTick()` will allow you to update a `TextView` with the seconds left or whatever (you also could do anything else you wanted to here). Then the `onFinish()` would allow you to, say, go to the next `Activity`

[Here is an answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917997/countdowntimer-trivia-game-score-android-java/13918114#13918114) that someone had issues with in case it helps.

Comment: Ha! I keep telling everyone that but they just don't believe it ;)

Comment: keep telling, you made me believe but how do I put it to reset when a question is answered?

Comment: You set your `CountdownTimer` object to `null`, reset the time, and re-initialize the `CountDownTimer` object

Comment: Don't feel bad...most do

Comment: I've edit my code.. please help.. this programming is annoying!

Comment: I don't know what the problem is now. And its best not to edit your original code but add to it. If its a new problem then a new post would be better for everyone or else it gets confusing. However, if you are needing to restart the timer then you need to instantiate an object of it. That way you can set it to `null` when you need to and instantiate a new timer object.

Comment: dumb question but how do I instantiate an object of it. Im from Croatia, sorry!

Comment: Well, I have never known any Croatians so I don't think you have anything to be sorry about, yet. You instantiate an object as you do a class. So if your countdowntimer class is `MyCountDown` then its like `MyCountDown countDown = new ``MyCountDown();`

Comment: I was saying sorry because I don't know how to instantiate a new timer object,,

Comment: I know...that was a little joke

Comment: Well, I solved it, I just had to put the allAnswers.clear() method before the generateQuestion() method and it works, feels awesome to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);

mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 15000);

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       //do something
   }
};
```