# Finish an activity after a time period

Tags: android, timer, android-activity

I am trying to develop a game like matching small pictures.My problem is that **i want to finish the game after a time period**.For instance in level 1 we have 10 seconds to match picture.I want to display remaining time also.I will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you also want to show the countdown, I would recommend a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). This has methods to take action at each "tick" which can be an interval you set in the constructor. And it's methods run on the `UI Thread` so you can easily update a `TextView`, etc...

In it's `onFinish()` method you can call `finish()` for your `Activity` or do any other appropriate action.

[See this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028062/how-to-make-a-timer-on-my-android-quiz-application/18028087#18028087)

**Edit with more clear example**

Here I have an inner-class which `extends CountDownTimer`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_xml);      
    // initialize Views, Animation, etc...

    // Initialize the CountDownClass
    timer = new MyCountDown(11000, 1000);
}

// inner class
private class MyCountDown extends CountDownTimer
{
    public MyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        frameAnimation.start();
        start();            
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        secs = 10;
       // I have an Intent you might not need one
        startActivity(intent);
        YourActivity.this.finish(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long duration) {
        cd.setText(String.valueOf(secs));
        secs = secs - 1;            
    }   
}
```

Comment: I tried it but my application gave a black screen.Should i write to whole code of my application like drawing pictures and click event for buttons etc. on onTick() method?

Comment: You still put your `Views` in your `Activity` with `setContentView(...)`. `onTick()` is where you would update your `TextView` or whatever if needed. Hang on, maybe I can post a short example *inside* the `Activity`.

Comment: @user1941070 I have updated with a more detailed example. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: yes i did it.thanks for help magician.i easliy integrated it.

Answer (score 0):

@nKn described it pretty well.

However, if you do not want to mess around with Handler. You always can delay the progress of the system code by writing:

```
Thread.sleep(time_at_mili_seconds);
```

You probably need to surround it with try-catch, which you can easily add via Source-> Surround with --> Try & catch.

Comment: No, it's just suspends the current thread.
You can find more information about it here: 
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I know what `Thread.sleep()` does. I'm saying you haven't indicated where this goes and if you put it on the `UI Thread` then it will, in fact, cause the `UI Thread` to hault. This is typically bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `postDelayed()` method of `Handler`...pass a `Thread` and specific time after which time the `Thread` will be executed as below...

```
private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mTimerExecutor = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //here, write your code
    }
};
```

Then call `postDelayed()` method of `Handler` to execute after your specified time as below...

```
 mTimerHandler.postDelayed(mTimerExecutor, 10000);
```