# Counter up/down timer view in Android

Tags: android, android-view, android-handler

I want to have a ViewPager with count up/down timer in each fragment. Given a time (i.e. 07:30), if the current time is 07:20, the timer should count down from 10:00. If the current time is 07:35, it should count up from 05:00.

What are some approaches I can take to accomplish this? Creating a custom view based on TextView with Timer class or are there any helpful third party custom view or views in Android SDK I can make use of?

**Update**

I read the code for CountDownTimer. It's using a Handler to tick every interval. I could write a similar Counter class that counts in the way I want above. I wonder if this solution is light enough to use multiple in ViewPager.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finish an activity after a time period](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488859/finish-an-activity-after-a-time-period)

Comment: @codeMagic How would this CountDownTimer count up?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this custom view:

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/holo-circular-progressbar/

Implement your own timer using the Android Timer class and feed the data to the above view:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Why do you choose Android Timer over Handler to tick the counter?