# Android count down timer explanation wanted

Tags: android, countdowntimer

in the android reference thing i found a page about countdowntimers :   [CountDownTimers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

it has this piece of code inside it:

```
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

I wanted to know what it is and if its an object or class and how i can use it as a timer for objects of a different class. can someone please explain how i would put this into my android project and use it. thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

the reference you quoted explains it very clear.

CountDownTimer is a **CLASS** and it's used to perform a determinated task until it's done.

The ***onTick*** method is used to perform an action on every tick (in milliseconds) and

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     //It will perform this task every millisecond until countdown finishes.
 }
```

The ***onFinish*** method performs a last task until the class end's its instance.

```
 public void onFinish() {
     //It will perform this task only once, when the countdown finishes.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks sorry if i was being a bit blind to the explantion in the android docs. I wanted ask what would i do if i wanted each object of the countdowntimer class to have their own event happening in the onFinish() method.

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

> public abstract class
>
> CountDownTimer
>
> extends Object

should answer one question.

As far as how to use it, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488859/finish-an-activity-after-a-time-period/22488980#22488980)