# Program should wait after Textfield changed its text

Tags: java, android

My Testprogram should change a **TextViews** text and after it is done, it should wait on second before the next text change. However my program runs the text changes instant behind each other:

```
    t.setText("Test!"); 
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        t.setText("Test - after 1 second!");    
        }
    },1000);
```

The first text is not even there close to a second.

Comment: Do you want a [CountDownTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488859/finish-an-activity-after-a-time-period/22488980#22488980)?

Comment: just want the system to wait 1 second before the text is changed automatically back

Comment: @Hamsty could I ask why you want to do this? Then maybe I can offer a different way of achieving this thats just as simple. As opposed to a runnable solution

Comment: A Textview should get some input - show its new input for a custom amount of time (e.g 1 second), and after this time it should do some math action without showing the content any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say why that wouldn't work from that limited amount of code but you can just add the post delayed to your `View`. You don't need a handler.

```
t.setText("Test!");
t.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       t.setText("Test - after 1 second!");
    }
}, 1000);
```

All `Views` in Android have a built in handler class.

Comment: What is **t**? How does the **t** have postDelayed() method?

Comment: im using Hamsty's code...I would assume its a TextView based on what he's trying to do. Furthermore I explained in my answer that all views in android have a handler built in, there is no need to create a new one

Comment: does a textview have __postDelayed__ method?

Comment: @Nabin Yes, TextView has a built in postDelayed method. Also you should be UP voting me for teaching you something new, not down voting me immediately for something you don't understand

Comment: could try this with a final view later :D However Textview should have postDelay()... guess you are right here!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the following:

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
```

inside the run method. Here **this** will refer to the handler object